# While scrolling tableview my waves animation getting halts in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, animation

I am doing iOS application with Objective-C, in that I am doing some voice recording and translating audio to speech, speech to audio. That speech/audio data showing in tableview. Its like how Siri doing in iPhone.

My issue is, I am displaying view top tableview and under UItableview showing animationview, its UIview object. Animationview working fine, but if I . scroll up/down the tableview, animationview getting distrub/halting the animation and after I release the tableview, its working fine again.

I tried to run it on Main thread again, but no use, still same issue happening.

My code is following :

```
-(void)startAnimation{

    animationTimer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.009 target:self selector:@selector(refreshAnimationView:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)refreshAnimationView:(NSTimer*)theTimer {

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{ // Your code to run on the main queue/thread

        //animation code here

          }
      }];
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to handle this.

Comment: Better to post your code what you had tried.

Comment: @DSDharma pls check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding your timer for `NSRunLoopCommonModes` after you create it.

`[NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop addTimer:animationTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];`

Comment: its lit bit working, but the thing is animation got slow compare with earlier animation is faster

Comment: anyway  i am giving vote up to your solution, its worked at least something to me. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, try moving your animation code out of the block. And make sure it does not have a heavy workload.

Comment: I did already, but while scrolling up/down animation getting lit bit slow.

Comment: @ObranS          -(void)startAnimation{
    animationTimer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.009 target:self selector:@selector(refreshAnimationView:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop addTimer:animationTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}